# mbed-OS porting to TivaC TM4123, Trouple with dynamic interrupt handling

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m, texas-instruments, mbed

Recently I'm trying to port mbed-OS to Tiva-C launchpad TM4C123, I am facing problem with file supplied by mbed which is cmsis_nvic.c and cmsis_nvic.h

This module is supposed to dynamically allocate the interrupt handler of OS timer to addressable function.(Or as far as I understand).

What happen is, The software jumps to "Hard Fault Handler" after executing the following line

```
vectors[i] = old_vectors[i];
```

Here's files which I use

```
#include "cmsis_nvic.h"
 
#define NVIC_RAM_VECTOR_ADDRESS (0x02000000)  // Vectors positioned at start of RAM
#define NVIC_FLASH_VECTOR_ADDRESS (0x0)       // Initial vector position in flash
 
void NVIC_SetVector(IRQn_Type IRQn, uint32_t vector) {
    uint32_t *vectors = (uint32_t*)SCB->VTOR;
    uint32_t i;
 
    // Copy and switch to dynamic vectors if the first time called
    if (SCB->VTOR == NVIC_FLASH_VECTOR_ADDRESS) {
        uint32_t *old_vectors = vectors;
        vectors = (uint32_t*)NVIC_RAM_VECTOR_ADDRESS;
        for (i=0; i<NVIC_NUM_VECTORS; i++) {
            vectors[i] = old_vectors[i];
        }
        SCB->VTOR = (uint32_t)NVIC_RAM_VECTOR_ADDRESS;
    }
    vectors[IRQn + 16] = vector;
}
 
uint32_t NVIC_GetVector(IRQn_Type IRQn) {
    uint32_t *vectors = (uint32_t*)SCB->VTOR;
    return vectors[IRQn + 16];
}
```

And here is cmsis_nvic.h

```
#ifndef MBED_CMSIS_NVIC_H
#define MBED_CMSIS_NVIC_H

#define NVIC_NUM_VECTORS      (154)   // CORE + MCU Peripherals
#define NVIC_USER_IRQ_OFFSET  16

#include "cmsis.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void NVIC_SetVector(IRQn_Type IRQn, uint32_t vector);
uint32_t NVIC_GetVector(IRQn_Type IRQn);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

and I am calling

> NVIC_SetVector(IRQn_Type IRQn, uint32_t vector)

from file us_ticker.c like this

> NVIC_SetVector(TIMER0A_IRQn, (uint32_t)us_ticker_irq_handler);

(my compiler is ARM GCC, I am using CDT for building, And GDB openOCD for debugging, and integrated all those tools on Eclipse)

**Can anyone please let me know what is going wrong here? or at least where should I debug or read to help me solve this problem???**

## UPDATE

I figured out part of the problem, The vector is not pointing to the first address of the target SRAM which should be

```
#define NVIC_RAM_VECTOR_ADDRESS (0x20000000)
```

instead of

```
#define NVIC_RAM_VECTOR_ADDRESS (0x02000000)
```

So now when calling NVIC_SetVector , the function is executed. But then when enabling the interrupt, Software still jumps to Hard Fault, I guess(just guessing or might be part of solution) that the defines in the header file are not configured correctly, Can someone explain to me what do they mean? and how to calculate the number of vector addresses? and what is the USER OFFSET?

Comment: What is the value of `i`? That is, if >0 then some got set ok. If not, use gdb to print the values. You are hardwiring `16`--is that `NVIC_USER_IRQ_OFFSET`? If so, use it. Could you be running past the end (e.g. `i` >= `NVIC_NUM_VECTORS`). Can you poke `vectors` with gdb? Is `VTOR` valid at start? (i.e. is one of the two correct values: 0/0x2000000). Is it fetching `old_vectors` or storing `vectors` the issue (i.e. do `x = old_vectors[i]; vectors[i] = x;`  and see which line faults)? I hope you're doing `-O0` for debug. Do you need `volatile` on any of the pointer variables?

Comment: I have updated the question? Could you please check it out and let me know if you have answer?

Comment: What is `TIMER0A_IRQn` defined as? Is it the vector number, or the interrupt number (vector number minus 16) as the code expects? Also, see table 2-9 in the datasheet; you have a _lot_ more than 66 peripheral IRQs...

Comment: `TIMER0A_IRQn` is the intterrupt number(CMSIS Complient driver), You are correct, I've updated the value of `NVIC_NUM_VECTORS` to 154. Now, the software doesn't jump to hard fault but still didn't work correctly as it still points to the original interrupt vector

Comment: Make sure that your linker script is not going to place data where you are expecting to locate your RAM vectors, otherwise you may be copying a vector table over data that you would like (possibly stack space), and likewise, your vector table may be overwritten by other data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue, here's what I have found

1- `NVIC_RAM_VECTOR_ADDRESS` wasn't the first address of my target RAM which should be `0x20000000'

2- Linker file should be update so that the stack pointer shouldn't write over the new copied vector table. So shift the RAM address by number of bytes that vector table should occupy.

3-(THE MAIN CAUSE) inside function `NVIC_SetVector`, `i` was declared as `uint32_t` and then compared to less than 255 pre-processor value. So compile get confused by comparing `uint32_t` with `uint8_t`, by adding `UL` to the pre-processor value, it solved the whole issue.